# Using array of custom hooks in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I've made a custom react hook `useMyElement` that returns a `JSX.Element` and some value, i.e.

```js
interface HookOutput {
  element: JSX.Element;
  value: any;
}
```

This works just fine but now I want to use a list of those elements and values, i.e.

```js
const hookElements = listOfArgs.map(args => useMyElement(args))
```

but I realize that this is gives unintended usage. I also get the following warning

> React Hook "useMyElement" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function. (react-hooks/rules-of-hooks)

How can I achieve a pattern like this? I.e. want to create a list of react components and return their stateful values from it as well without using something like redux.

Comment: But then first wouldn't be available for use but I guess that would be alright. I disagree with "don't use hooks inside hooks" tho. You'd always use hooks inside hooks, that's almost the reason for having hooks.

Comment: What is the larger goal here? There could be workable ways of achieving that while obeying the hook rules.

Comment: The larger goal is my last sentence: " I.e. want to create a list of react components and return their stateful values from it as well without using something like redux."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, firstly, I would make a small change in the 'useMyElement' hook.
The interface for HookOutput would look like this:

```js
interface HookOutput {
    elements: JSX.Element[];
    values: any[];
  }
```

The hook will expose the array of elements and its corresponding values instead of exposing single element and its value.

Now, the hook would look something like this:

```js
const useMyElements = (args: any[]): HookOutput => {
    const [elements, setElements] = useState<JSX.Element[]>([]);
    const [values, setValues] = useState<any[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        args.map(arg => {
            // initialize elements and values
        })
    }, [])

    return {
        elements,
        values
    }
}
```

I was not sure about the type of args that you would be providing, so, its upto you to initialize the list of elements from the args.